# passing object to "detailed" view controllers multiple levels deep

Tags: ios, storyboard

In iOS, using Storyboards, when I want to pass an object to my detailed view controller, I usually do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowRouteViewController"]) {
        if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setRoute:)]) {
            [destination setValue:self.route forKey:@"route"];
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sense to me if my next view controller needs this object.  What I was wondering is, what's the best practice for passing an object multiple screens deep.  For example, if I have 4 view controllers:

A->B->C->D

A has the route property, D needs the route property, but B and C do not, how does D get the route property?  I've been just adding the property to B and C so that the property can trickle down to the view controller I need, but I wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way to do this.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use appdelegate. Declare your variables in AppDelegate (nsstring,nsinteger,nsarray .. etc). Now you can call your variables like this:
self.appDelegate = [[UIapplication sharedapplication]delegate];
self.appDelegate.yourVariable